# How to get input from user, then check if the multiple lists matches the input

Tags: python, list, input

I'm a fairly beginner in Py, tho I am trying to automate a task in something, we are dubbing a webtoon series, and we need to train since we are quite a lot, I need a program, that check the user input for a number, then check multiples list (episode 1 (3) ) for the number of characters in it.

I also need if someone is willing to help more, to do this with name, I nearly got it, then got stuck, and I got mad so I deleted everything, but ht code was bad, so no remorse. so you put a bunch of names, and it will output the episodes with these names in it.

```
ep_1 = [3]    these are the numbers of character in an episode
ep_2 = [1]
ep_3 = [1]
ep_4 = [1]
ep_5 = [3]
eps = ep_1.extend(ep_2 + ep_3 + ep_4)

print("version : 1.0 : Dispo j'usqu'a l'episode 50")

print(" ")
print(" ")
print(" ")

print("Noms des personnages a utiliser : john isen arlo doc directeur elaine sera cecile blyke")
print(" ")
print(" ")
print(" ")

choix = input("Numbers of characters, or names of characters ?")

if choix := ("nombre"):
    nombre_persos = int(input("how many characters ? : "))
    if nombre_persos in eps:
        print("oui")    this just help me verify the if statement, i just dont know what to do next, and even if im doing anything good
```

Comment: im gonna learn what it does, i'll come back, thanks a lot

Comment: any idea how i should use it in my case ?

Comment: Please use proper English grammar.

Comment: check profile, im not english

Comment: @Supkdk Oh, sorry. well I posted an answer for you. If it helps, please accept it by clicking the check mark

Comment: @Supkdk oh, Mehdi Mostafavi's answer helped you the most. Do I have to improve my answer?

Comment: your answer helped me even more tbh, but here you guys are not the problem, i am, since im a beginner, everytime i get an answer, i need to learn the functions used....

Comment: @ppwater but i answered you in your response

Comment: @Supkdk please don't edit other peoples answers if you have questions to the author. That's for what we have the comment function.

Comment: first time on stack sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enumerate`. Here is the code:

```
ep_1 = [3]
ep_2 = [1]
ep_3 = [1]
ep_4 = [1]
ep_5 = [3]
eps = ep_1 + ep_2 + ep_3 + ep_4

print("version : 1.0 : Dispo j'usqu'a l'episode 50")

print(" ")
print(" ")
print(" ")

print("Noms des personnages a utiliser : john isen arlo doc directeur elaine sera cecile blyke")
print(" ")
print(" ")
print(" ")

choix = input("Numbers of characters, or names of characters ?")

if choix == ("nombre"):
    nombre_persos = int(input("how many characters ? : "))
    if nombre_persos in eps:
        print("oui")
        eps2 = eps
        for (i, item) in enumerate(eps2, start=1):
            if item == nombre_persos:
                print('ep_'+str(i))
```

And see this for enumerate:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: works, but if there is multiple episode with 1 character(example) it shows only one...

Comment: Oh, Okay, I'll try to fix that.

Comment: @Supkdk I fixed it, please try it. and if it doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: also need to way to output the name of the episode =)

Comment: YAY it works ! wish i could understand how tho

Comment: maybe its not for my level to understand this ? should i even try to ?

Comment: Oh, I explaned. Please see the link I provided. and you can google `enumerate python`

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll read that, after reading that, would i be able in addition to outputting(grammar) the numbers of character, output the names ?

Comment: ep_25 = ("isen", "sera", "remi", "elaine", "doc") in this form maybe ? idk how to mix Int number and string

Comment: You should post another question for that if you don't understand

Comment: sorry to ask, but maybe you can answer me that in chat ? in private ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map{}`. Something like this:

```
n = int(input())
for episode,characters in episodes.items():
    if n == characters:
        print(episode)
```